# How to get hidden/deleted project back

Tags: android, android-studio, setup-project, source-code-protection

I was working on an android project. Last week, I saved 2 copies of this project in 2 different drives for backup. Since that day I make many changes in my project (80% changes). A couple of minutes ago, I copy my updated project from one drive and paste two other drives (backup drives) but when I came back to the android studio and run my project on the emulator, it was the old project.

I go back to two backup drives and check but there is also an old project version. I don't know where It goes.

I really need help. Thanks

Comment: Try to check the local history in Android Studio, right click on your project in Android Studio and select [Local Histroy] => [Show History]

Comment: You should use version control system like git or svn, that will prevent operation mistakes.

Comment: I checked there but that history only shows changes in a specific file. In my case, the new version of the project has many new java, XML, and drawable files.

Comment: AIMIN PAN you are right but for now, I need solution to bring the new project back.